# significance of colocated parameter with required tab in template-info.xml

Tags: xml, dependencies, weblogic

In **template-info.xml** file contained inside template.jar
We generally have the information about template like name, version, type, author info etc..
like:

```
<domain-template-info
    version="11.1.5.0"
    type="Extension Template"
    name="xyz"
    author="Samanta">
```

We can also have a **dependency** tab which lists out the dependency information about the template, ie: when the template is chosen to be applied to the domain then the templates mentioned inside **required** sub tab are also deployed to the domain.
like:

```
 <dependency>
    <and>
      <requires name="A" colocated="true"/>
      <requires name="B" colocated="true"/>
      <requires name="C" colocated="true"/>
 </and>
  </dependency>
```

Here if xyz is applied to the domain then A, B and C will also be applied to the domain before applying xyz.

Can some one tell me the significance of the **colocated** parameter with **requires** tab?